# Why not using static variable directly in Swift?

Tags: swift

I found this in the Mozilla Firefox for iOS repository.

```
static let WebServerSharedInstance = WebServer()

class var sharedInstance: WebServer {
    return WebServerSharedInstance
}
```

Why would you create a new variable that just returns the same variable when you could do the same in one line like this?

```
static let sharedInstance = WebServer()
```

Comment: I have modified my answer, please make sure you still consider it as accepted.

Comment: Your answer is fantastic, giving two reasons why that might be. And thank you for giving me a heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked into the code and I think I have misunderstood the context:

```
class WebServer {
    static let WebServerSharedInstance = WebServer()

    class var sharedInstance: WebServer {
        return WebServerSharedInstance
    }
}
```

While you can always use `WebServer.WebServerSharedInstance` to access the singleton, a subclass of `WebServer` can override `sharedInstance`.

```
class MyServer : WebServer {
    override class var sharedInstance: MyServer {
        return MyServer()
    }
}
```

However, I have found no example in the code doing that so the original answer below is probably correct.

**Original answer:**

You are right. There is absolutely no reason to do that.

This has been probably translated directly from Objective-C, which uses similar syntax for singletons.

Also, with Swift 1.0 we weren't very sure how to create singletons and whether `static let` on a class is Thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion is that WebServerSharedInstance is a **global variable** declared at the top level of the file which lives as long as the file lives which is as long as the program runs --> You can use that variable in all other files

Comment: Why isn't ```WebServerSharedInstance``` a global variable?

Comment: WebServerSharedInstance is a global variable which you can use in all other files of your program.

Comment: Then why would you need the second variable?

Comment: You are copying the value of your global variable to do some other calculation and keep the value of your global variable clean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the context. But let me explain one of the key differences between

```
// 1
class var sharedInstance: WebServer {
    return WebServerSharedInstance
}
```

vs

```
// 2
static let sharedInstance = WebServer()
```

`1` is computed variable which gets evaluated each time you access, while `2` get initialized lazily and evaluated only once.

If later in your code someone reassigns the `WebServerSharedInstance`

The `1` will return the new value while `2` will keep returning the initial value if it got initialized before.

Comment: You don't know what a computed variable is !!! a variable can be computed. This means that the variable, instead of having a value, has functions. One function, the setter, is called when the variable is assigned to. The other function, the getter, is called when the variable is referred to.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But for reference. 
`You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by removing the get keyword and its braces`

Comment: sorry you right. didnt know that you can remove the keyword